# *** glibc detected *** ./m: free(): invalid next size (fast) on trying to free heap memory

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, free, glibc

I have a small code which allocates some memory on heap and then after its use tries to free it.
I am getting this error with memory map.

The Code is ::

```
void merge(int *arr, int start, int mid, int end)
{
     int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, tmp1 = 0, siz = 0;
     int *pt = NULL;
     j = start, k = mid+1, tmp1 = start;

     siz = (end - start) + 1;

     if ((pt = malloc(siz * sizeof(int))) == NULL) /* line 32 */
     {
         printf("\n ERROR Aloocating mem \n");
         return;
     }

     while (j <= mid && k <= end)
     {
        if (arr[j] <= arr[k])
        {
          pt[tmp1] = arr[j];
          ++j;
          ++tmp1;
        }
        if (arr[j] > arr[k])
        {
          pt[tmp1] = arr[k]; /* line 48 */
          ++k;
          ++tmp1;
        }

      } 
       while (j <= mid)
       {
          pt[tmp1] = arr[j]; /* line 56 */
          ++tmp1;
          ++j;
       }
        while (k <= end)
        {
           pt[tmp1] = arr[k];
           ++k;
           ++tmp1;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < siz; i++)
        {
           arr[end] = pt[end]; /* line 69 */
           --end;
        }   

        free(pt);   
    }
```

The error i am getting is ::

```
*** glibc detected *** ./m: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0940c008 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6b161)[0x213161]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6c9b8)[0x2149b8]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0x217a9d]
./m[0x80486d8]
./m[0x8048562]
./m[0x8048526]
./m[0x8048542]
./m[0x804874b]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0x1bebd6]
./m[0x8048441]
======= Memory map: ========
001a8000-002fb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1535       /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
002fb000-002fd000 r--p 00153000 08:01 1535       /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
002fd000-002fe000 rw-p 00155000 08:01 1535       /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
002fe000-00301000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00483000-0049e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1712996    /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
0049e000-0049f000 r--p 0001a000 08:01 1712996    /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
0049f000-004a0000 rw-p 0001b000 08:01 1712996    /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
007f8000-00815000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1708381    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
00815000-00816000 r--p 0001c000 08:01 1708381    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
00816000-00817000 rw-p 0001d000 08:01 1708381    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
00b38000-00b39000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1317230    /home/abhi/Desktop/ad/A1/misc/m
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 08:01 1317230    /home/abhi/Desktop/ad/A1/misc/m
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 1317230    /home/abhi/Desktop/ad/A1/misc/m
0940c000-0942d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7600000-b7621000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7621000-b7700000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b777e000-b777f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b778c000-b7790000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bf8b5000-bf8ca000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted
```

I went through the answers of some of the similar questions on SO and learnt that it is a memory error.

So i ran the coded with valgrind and got the following output (Not the complete output)

```
==4494== 
==4494== Invalid write of size 4
==4494==    at 0x8048650: merge (merge.c:48)
==4494==    by 0x8048561: merge_sort (merge.c:20)
==4494==    by 0x8048525: merge_sort (merge.c:18)
==4494==    by 0x8048541: merge_sort (merge.c:19)
==4494==    by 0x8048766: main (merge.c:89)
==4494==  Address 0x41920ac is 4 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==4494==    at 0x4023AB8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:207)
==4494==    by 0x80485CB: merge (merge.c:32)
==4494==    by 0x8048561: merge_sort (merge.c:20)
==4494==    by 0x8048525: merge_sort (merge.c:18)
==4494==    by 0x8048541: merge_sort (merge.c:19)
==4494==    by 0x8048766: main (merge.c:89)
==4494== 
==4494== Invalid write of size 4
==4494==    at 0x8048680: merge (merge.c:56)
==4494==    by 0x8048561: merge_sort (merge.c:20)
==4494==    by 0x8048525: merge_sort (merge.c:18)
==4494==    by 0x8048541: merge_sort (merge.c:19)
==4494==    by 0x8048766: main (merge.c:89)
==4494==  Address 0x41920b0 is 8 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==4494==    at 0x4023AB8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:207)

==4494== Invalid read of size 4
==4494==    at 0x80486D5: merge (merge.c:69)
==4494==    by 0x8048561: merge_sort (merge.c:20)
==4494==    by 0x8048541: merge_sort (merge.c:19)
==4494==    by 0x8048766: main (merge.c:89)
==4494==  Address 0x41920ec is 8 bytes after a block of size 12 alloc'd
==4494==    at 0x4023AB8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:207)
==4494==    by 0x80485CB: merge (merge.c:32)
==4494==    by 0x8048561: merge_sort (merge.c:20)
==4494==    by 0x8048541: merge_sort (merge.c:19)
==4494==    by 0x8048766: main (merge.c:89)
```

I am not able to rectify the problem the `malloc` looks fine to me. I am allocating `siz * sizeof(int)` bytes (int is 4 bytes on my machine) and then using the allocated memory in form if array.

If someone point out the mistake i am doing and the explain the reasons, it will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This is telling you that you're writing outside the bounds of your allocated buffer.  You should step through your code, and confirm that all indices are exactly as you expect.

Comment: Use `valgrind` and compile your code with `gcc -Wall -g` and learn to use the debugger.

Comment: @Bill Please see my edit in code for Line numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on Daniel correctly pointing out that `pt[end]` is incorrect, assume the following function call:

```
int values[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
merge(values, 4, 5, 6);
```

In `merge`, pt is allocated to be large enough for (6 - 4) + 1 = `3 int`s.
`tmp1` is set to 4.
On line 48, you do `pt[tmp1] = arr[k]`, but this is `pt[4] = arr[0]`, and you're writing on memory outside of `pt`!

Comment: Oh, wow, completely overlooked that line. All I saw was the original initialisation to 0.

Comment: Yep, the double-initialization of `tmp1` threw me too, at first. :)

Comment: @Bill Thanks Bill for pointing out the mistake i did..

Answer (score 3):

You're using tmp1 as the index, and initializing it to `start` instead of 0.  In detail:

```
 j = start, k = mid+1, tmp1 = start;

 siz = (end - start) + 1;

 if ((pt = malloc(siz * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
```

`pt` goes from 0 to (end-start) + 1, yet you begin accessing it with the index `tmp1 = start`.

`tmp1` should be 0.  Concretely, if `end` is 10, and `start` is 8, you will allocate 3 bytes... and you do NOT want the `tmp1` index to begin at 8 in a 3 element array!

Comment: Thanks wilsonmuchaelpatrick

Answer (score 2):

```
arr[end] = pt[end];
```

accesses `pt` out of bounds unless `start == 0`. The last valid index for `pt` is `end-start`.

Also, in

```
 while (j <= mid && k <= end)
 {
    if (arr[j] <= arr[k])
    {
      pt[tmp1] = arr[j];
      ++j;
      ++tmp1;
    }
    if (arr[j] > arr[k])
    {
      pt[tmp1] = arr[k];
      ++k;
      ++tmp1;
    }

  }
```

in the second `if`, `j` can be larger than `mid` - if it was `== mid` on the start of the iteration - you should better replace the second `if` with an `else`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I surely missed that. my bad.I will edit the code and check.